# Using the angular 14 inject() and how to run this in a test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Doing some changes to my code as I wanted to try out some new features so I switched from using a constructor() to using inject() to import services. Now my test is failing and I cant seem to find any documentation about this on how to test this.

How can I change my test to use the inject() way.

```
old code

export ResetService {
   constructor(private serviceOne: ServiceOne) 
   {}
}

// updated 

export ResetService {
   #serviceOne = inject(ServiceOne) 
}

// old testing code
describe('ResetService', () => {
  let service: ResetService;
  let serviceOne: jasmine.SpyObj<OrderRepository> = jasmine.createSpyObj(OrderRepository, [
    'clearOrders',
  ]);

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new ResetService(serviceOne);// giving an error with inject()
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `inject` inside your service, You explicitly couple your service to the Angular DI system. To make Angular DI work in your test, you will have to use Angular's [TestBed](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#angular-testbed). Using `TestBed`, you can configure a module and provide services that can be injected during testing:

```
describe('ResetService', () => {
  let resetService: ResetService;

  beforeEach(() => {
     // Create a spy for your dependency
     let serviceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<OrderRepository> = 
          jasmine.createSpyObj(OrderRepository, [
          'clearOrders',
      ]);
      // Provide both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency in the testing module
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
          ResetService
          { provide: OrderRepository, useValue: serviceSpy}
        ]
      });

      // Get a reference to your service-to-test
      resetService= TestBed.inject(ResetService);
   });


  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(resetService).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```